# i18n addResourceBundle mocks shows error i18n not defined

Tags: react-testing-library, i18next

I am using react testing library to test my code and I have used i18n.addResourceBundle to add some translations on the fly. I am trying to test its and have

jest.mock('i18n', () => ({
__esModule: true,
default: { addResourceBundle: jest.fn() }
}))

BUt when I try to do snapshot, it keeps saying i18n.addResourceBundle is not defined

Comment: are you using useTranslation or which?

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking i18next improperly.

The usage of i18next looks like:

```js
import i18next from 'i18next';

export const i18n = i18next.init({
...
// config
...
});

// somewhere else in the code

i18n.addResourceBundle();
//-^ this is an instance of i18next
```

That means that you need to return an object with `init` function which returns an instance with `addResourceBundle`.

```js
jest.mock('i18n', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: {
    init(config) {
      return {
        // this is the instance
        addResourceBundle: jest.fn(),
      };
    },
  },
}));
```